# VSCode Keep asking for passphrase of SSH key

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have recently upgrade my VSCode version 1.10.2. 
As I put passphrase on my private SSH key, it started to ask for it frequently even when I entered it multiple times, which is very annoying. Is there anyway I can get rid of it? Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Added MacOS instructions in an answer below :)

Comment: If you're using windows, try launching from git bash to have VSCode inherit the SSH environment https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/sourcecontrol/faq#:~:text=Can%20I%20use%20SSH%20Git,to%20inherit%20its%20SSH%20environment.

Answer (score 41):

**Yes**, you can avoid this prompt, without removing the passphrase.

To do so is usually fairly simple and relies on the `ssh-agent` program. First, before starting VSCode, at a bash shell prompt, run:

```
$ eval `ssh-agent`
```

This will start an `ssh-agent` process in the background that will remember the decrypted private key in its memory.  The reason for `eval` is `ssh-agent` prints two environment variable settings that need to be added to the shell.  (You can also just run it normally, then manually copy and paste its output back into the shell.)

Next, run:

```
$ ssh-add
```

This will prompt you for your passphrase, after which `ssh-agent` will provide private key services to any other process that needs it.

Finally, start VSCode from the same shell you ran the first command:

```
$ code
```

This way VSCode will inherit the environment variables it needs to get key services from `ssh-agent`, and therefore will not prompt for your passphrase so long as the `ssh-agent` process continues running.

#### Further References

Unfortunately, despite it being so useful, good (concise, readable) documentation on `ssh-agent` is hard to find.  But here are some possibilities:

- The [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-agent) is, as is typical for man pages, heavy on detail and light on examples.
- The article http://rabexc.org/posts/using-ssh-agent is pretty good, and it covers some more advanced situations, especially agent forwarding.
- The [Stack Exchange question, "what's the purpose of ssh-agent?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72552/whats-the-purpose-of-ssh-agent) is also good.

Comment: Mint XFCE 19.3: this worked for me until reboot. I created a new RSA key with Seahorse and this seems persistent

Comment: WHEN GENERATING AN SSH KEY, DO I NEED TO BE MINDFUL OF SAVING THE KEY FINGERPRINT AND RANDOMART SOMEWHERE, WHILE IT HAS ALREADY SAVED THE PUBLIC KEY IN THE SPECIFIED DIRECTORY?

Comment: @SharjeelFaiq See https://superuser.com/questions/22535/what-is-randomart-produced-by-ssh-keygen

Answer (score 13):

For Windows 10, if you have stumbled across this issue using the *Remote - SSH* plugin, run the following in powershell (as admin):

```
# Make sure you're running PowerShell as an Administrator
Set-Service ssh-agent -StartupType Automatic
Start-Service ssh-agent
Get-Service ssh-agent
```

(As suggested by the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_setting-up-the-ssh-agent) that is pointed to by [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/354#issuecomment-493786645) on a git (non-)issue.)

Comment: Can also call `ssh-add` in your powershell init scripts, eg: `$HOME\Documents\PowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`

Comment: @darmual Doing the `ssh-add` afterwards in the vscode terminal did the job for me +1

Comment: @Efren, does that also work if your ssh certificate is passphrased?

Answer (score 10):

The only solution I've found was remove the passphrase:

```
ssh-keygen -p
```

It will ask your current passphrase and leave blank the new passphrase to remove it.

Answer (score 3):

For any **MacOS** users encountering issues, Github has some [great documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent) on this issue.

Make sure to change the `Host` to whatever git provider you are using (e.g. github.com, bitbucket.org) and make the `IdentityFile` point to the file name of your private key (e.g. `~/.ssh/id_ed25519`, `~/.ssh/id_rsa`)

```
Host github.com
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

Make sure to replace the file path in the command for adding the SSH key to KeyChain as well

```
ssh-add --apple-use-keychain ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

Answer (score 1):

Disable auto fetching with `git.autofetch = false` in the settings

Answer (score 1):

There is a great guide on how to solve it in Windows here:

https://www.cgranade.com/blog/2016/06/06/ssh-keys-in-vscode.html

Summary:

- Install Required Software (Putty)
- Setup Private Keys (use ssh-keygen which will create private and public keys in .ssh folder)
- Set up SSH Agent: have Pageant tool run on Windows startup
- import your key to ppk format

> Run PuTTYgen from the Start Menu and select File → Load Key.... From there, navigate to C:\Users\.ssh\ and select id_rsa (the private key). You may have to drop down the file types selector in the dialog box to see this, as PuTTYgen defaults to filtering out everything but files ending in *.ppk. Once selected, you’ll be prompted by PuTTY to unlock your key by typing in your passphrase. Do so, and PuTTYgen will show the corresponding public key. Select File → Save private key to export your private key in PuTTY, rather than OpenSSH, format. I suggest saving it as id_rsa.ppk in the same folder as id_rsa

- run Pageant

> Finally, run Pageant from the Start Menu (in the future, this will be handled automatically by the shortcut we created above). This will add a new icon to your system tray. It may be hidden by the arrow; if so, click the arrow to make all fo the system tray icons visible. Right-click on Pageant and select Add Key. Browse to where you saved id_rsa.ppk and select it. You’ll be prompted to unlock your key. Upon doing so, your unlocked key will then be made available in Pageant until you log out or quit Pageant.

- Add fingerprints, in shell run one of those two (depending on your needs)

  'C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\plink.exe' git@github.com

  'C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\plink.exe' git@bitbucket.org
- Configure GIT_SSH to be C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\plink.exe

Comment: Updated my answer with details (summary only, tried to keep it short)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using windows, try launching VS Code from a Git Bash that you've already unlocked the SSH key in, so that VSCode inherits the SSH environment.

> Can I use SSH Git authentication with VS Code?
>
> Yes, though VS Code works most easily with SSH keys without a
> passphrase. If you have an SSH key with a passphrase, you'll need to
> launch VS Code from a Git Bash prompt to inherit its SSH environment.

[https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/sourcecontrol/faq#:~:text=Can%20I%20use%20SSH%20Git,to%20inherit%20its%20SSH%20environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/sourcecontrol/faq#:%7E:text=Can%20I%20use%20SSH%20Git,to%20inherit%20its%20SSH%20environment).

Comment: WHEN GENERATING AN SSH KEY, DO I NEED TO BE MINDFUL OF SAVING THE KEY FINGERPRINT AND RANDOMART SOMEWHERE, WHILE IT HAS ALREADY SAVED THE PUBLIC KEY IN THE SPECIFIED DIRECTORY?