# Why does the VS Code terminal always ask for my SSH passphrase?

Tags: git, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, ssh, terminal

I'm using Ubuntu 20.10 and VS Code 1.52.1. I followed GitHub's instructions to [generate an SSH key, add it to the ssh-agent](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent), and [add it to my GitHub account](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account). When I use Ubuntu's built-in **Terminal** app, everything works correctly for repos that I clone with SSH:

```sh
git clone git@github.com:octocat/Spoon-Knife.git
cd Spoon-Knife
git fetch
```

It doesn't ask for my passphrase every time. Similarly, if I open that cloned repo (or any other) in VS Code and run the **Git: Fetch** command (or **Git: Push** etc), it runs successfully without asking for my passphrase.

But when I run `git fetch` from the same directory inside of the VS Code integrated terminal, I get this message:

```
Enter passphrase for key '/home/sam/.ssh/id_ed25519':
```

Even if I enter my passphrase for this invocation, it still keeps asking for my passphrase every time I run `git fetch`. How can I fix this and make it act like the Ubuntu default terminal? (I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42707896/5044950), but it seems to be for the VS Code UI rather than the integrated terminal, and none of the answers worked; most of them were steps that I had already followed as per the GitHub instructions linked above.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in your VS Code settings to see if you have **Terminal › Integrated: Inherit Env** unchecked:

[image: Settings UI with inheritEnv set to false]

If it is, re-check it:

[image: Settings UI with inheritEnv set to true]

Alternatively, use the **Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)** command to open your settings file and look for this line:

```json
"terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false
```

If it's present, remove it (since `true` is the default for that setting).